# Find all combinations UNIX

Tags: unix

I want to find all possible combinations of the numbers 1, 2, 3. Namely, I want a command of the form:

```
$ echo ______
```

That will return the following:

```
11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33
```

It doesn't have to necessarily be in that order, but all those combinations must show. How would I go about doing something like this?

EDIT:

So far, I've learned about using metacharacters, character classes specifically, and thought I could use them somehow. Something along the lines of [1-3][1-3]. Obviously, this won't work but that's where I've started. I've also found the "find" command might be useful so I've been looking into how find works but its a lot more complicated than I thought...

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=what+have+you+tried

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this?  (If you're using bash, anyway.)

```
localhost-2:~ $ echo {1,2,3}{1,2,3}
11 12 13 21 22 23 31 32 33
localhost-2:~ $ echo {1,2,3}{1,2,3},
11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33,
```

Comment: yea! this is what I want, what is the significance between using {} vs [] in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use bash's expansion things:

```
echo {1..3}{1..3}
```